# Have to Convert the code from native Android to Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I get a problem with converting code from native Android JAVA code to Xamarin C# Android code:
 I have a class ThumbnailStrip:

- How to set Orientation
- LayOutParameters
- OnClickListener

  ```
  class ThumbnailStrip extends FrameLayout {
    Context con;
    Rotator rotator;
    CustomImageView images;
    int count;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    double viewHeight, viewWidth;
    private boolean isDown;
    private float X,Y,dX,dY,diffX,diffY;
    private boolean NEXT,PREVIOUS;
    LinearLayout thumbLayout;

    public ThumbnailStrip(Context context, SfRotator _imageSlider, double height, double width) {
      super(context);
      con = context;
      rotator = _imageSlider;
      thumbLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
      if (rotator.getNavigationStripPosition() == NavigationStripPosition.Top || rotator.getNavigationStripPosition() == NavigationStripPosition.Bottom)
          thumbLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
      else
          thumbLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      if (thumbLayout.getOrientation() == LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL) {
          viewHeight = height-10;
          viewWidth = width / 5;
      } else {
          viewHeight = height / 5;
          viewWidth = width-10;
      }
      createThumbnails(con);
  }

  Timer thumbTimer;boolean thumbStart,isDynamicView;
  public ThumbnailStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  private void createThumbnails(Context con) {

      if (rotator.getDataSource() != null) {
          count = rotator.getDataSource().size();
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              View view;
              if(rotator.getAdapter()!=null && rotator.getAdapter().getThumbnailView(rotator,i)!=null) {
                  view = rotator.getAdapter().getThumbnailView(rotator, i);
                  isDynamicView = true;
              }
              else {

                  if(rotator.getDataSource().get(i).getContent()!=null) {
                      view = rotator.getDataSource().get(i).getContent();
                      isDynamicView = false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                      int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(rotator.getDataSource().get(i).getImageContent(), "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
                      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                      view=imageView;
                      isDynamicView = false;


                  }
              }
              view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(rotator.getWidth(),rotator.getHeight()));
              images = new CustomImageView(con,view , (float) viewWidth, (float) viewHeight,isDynamicView);
              images.setClickable(true);
              images.setPadding(6, 0, 0, 0);
              if(thumbLayout.getOrientation()==LinearLayout.VERTICAL) {
                  images.setPadding(6, 6, 0, 0);
              }
              images.setIndex(i);
              if (i == rotator.getSelectedIndex()) {
                  images.setSelectedImage(true);
              }
              images.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
              LayoutParams itemLayout;
              itemLayout = new LayoutParams((int) viewWidth, (int) (viewHeight), Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
              itemLayout.setMargins(6, 6, 0, 0);
              thumbLayout.addView(images, itemLayout);


  //Especially I don't know how to set OnCliCkListener,Please help me with a solution.

              images.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      if (rotator.isEnableAutoPlay()) {
                          rotator.isAnimationinteracted = true;
                      }
                      final CustomImageView imgView = (CustomImageView) v;
                      if (imgView.getIndex() > rotator.getSelectedIndex())
                          rotator.setPlayDirection(PlayDirection.MoveBackward);
                      else
                          rotator.setPlayDirection(PlayDirection.MoveForward);
                      if (imgView.getIndex() != rotator.getSelectedIndex()) {
                          rotator.setSelectedIndex((imgView).getIndex());
                          if (rotator.isEnableAutoPlay()) {
                              thumbStart = true;
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
          this.addView(thumbLayout);
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Pls, Help me to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Layout Parameters in Xamarin is like this:

```
    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
                ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);
    linear.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams;
```

Cheking Orientation like this:

```
    if(linear.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal){

    }
```

onCLick Listener in Java will convert into Events like this

```
    image.Click += (sender, e) => {

    };
```

Comment: @suraj ForOnClickListener I have a doubt in PlayDirection and in isAnimationinteracted.Can u Pls explain that part.

Comment: You need to see those code on this classes Rotator and CustomImageView to know. It is custom and I cant explain it to you unless I see the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
images.Click += (sender, e) =>
{

    if (rotator.isEnableAutoPlay())
    {
        rotator.isAnimationinteracted = true;
    }

    CustomImageView imgView = (CustomImageView)view;
    if (imgView.getIndex() > rotator.getSelectedIndex())
         rotator.playDirection = PlayDirection.MoveBackward;
    else
         rotator.playDirection = PlayDirection.MoveForward;
         if (imgView.getIndex() != rotator.getSelectedIndex())
         {
             rotator.setSelectedIndex((imgView).getIndex());
             if (rotator.isEnableAutoPlay())
             {
                  thumbStart = true;
             }
         }
};
```